# Django get user permissions from queryset

Tags: django

In my application each user is given access to one of the four groups (I have 4 groups created). I have to check if user has ceritan permissions to access a form. I am obtaining the user from `self.request.user` and getting the queryset of the corresponding user model.

```
group = self.request.user.groups.all()
```

But if I try to do

```
self.request.user.groups.all().values('permissions')
```

It is printing the permissions in such a way that each of them has a number associated to it. I want to check if there is any way to check if the user has the access to ceritan model based on the queryset I got. I mean is there any method alike `has_perm('')` to perform the above task. I have searched about it on google and stackoverflow. but could not find the satisfying results. So, is there any way to perform the above operations ??

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.values(..)` you obtain the values of the *primary* keys, and furthermore `.values(..)` should typically only be used for some specific cases.

You can query for the permissions with:

```
Permission.objects.filter(group__user=request.user).distinct()
```

This will give you the `Permission` objects assigned to group(s) in which `request.user` is a member.

We need to use `.distinct()` here, since if a permission is added to *multiple* groups in which the user is a member, that permission will be returned *multiple* times.